# Can I change the randomness in arc4random_uniform?

Tags: swift3

Can I change the randomness in arc4random_uniform, so e.g. if I have 2 numbers and I want to randomly pick one of them, but I want a 60% chance of picking the first one, and then a 40% chance of picking the last one?

Is that possible, if not, how can I then solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get a random number between 0 and 100; if it is 60 or below, take number one, otherwise take number two.

```
import Darwin

func getNumber ( ) -> Int {
    let number1 = 3;
    let number2 = 5;
    let rnd = arc4random() % 101
    return (rnd <= 60 ? number1 : number2)
}

print("\(getNumber())")
```

60% of the time you get `3`, 40% of the time you get `5`.